# Retina Graphics for websites on iPhone is wasteful

Tags: iphone, css, image, retina-display

Using CSS media queries for background images is great, but what about regular embedded images?

[www.retinajs.com](http://www.retinajs.com) and [www.retina-images.complexcompulsions.com](http://retina-images.complexcompulsions.com) are great but I have one problem with both of them.  They serve retina graphics to all retina devices regardless of size.  The iPhone for example doesn't need retina graphics served to it because it shrinks the images anyway.  To have a double resolution image served on an iPhone with (perhaps) and slow connection is wasteful.

Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: well if you're going through the trouble to show Retina graphics you might as well design your site to be responsive. In that case iPhone graphics wouldn't be shrunken.

Comment: with responsive design, I can only see using background images for everything as a solution.  For images within the html there's no other solution unless you create two divs for everything, 1 for retina and 1 for regular and display:block the appropriate one.

Answer (score 2):

Matt Wilcox built http://adaptive-images.com/ to solve this problem. It requires a bit of server-side code though.

In addition, the W3C are looking into `<img srcset="big.png 1100w, medium.png 500w, small.png 200w">`, but I'm unsure if it's been enshrined in a standard (there was lots of disagreement) or whether webkit ever got around to implementing it.

Comment: thanks,  looked into that one but trying to find something a little simpler if possible.

Comment: Alas that's about as simple as it gets right, short of loading higher-res with javascript if/when they're needed.

Comment: In addition, "retina" displays complicate the issue - they're twice the resolution of "normal" displays so they'll need the higher resolution graphics anyway! This is not an easy problem...

Comment: Looked more at the adaptive-images solution but it still has the same problem as outlined in the following link:             http://adaptive-images.com/details.htm#alternate-js

Answer (score 0):

As @OllyHodgson suggested *Adaptive Image* is a pretty good solution, even more the extended script provided by [johannheyne](https://github.com/johannheyne/Adaptive-Images)  wich cover your exact problem, control over what and how should be served as retina image. Hope this helps!